# (MSaccess to MySQL) FROM subqueries with alias

Tags: mysql, ms-access, subquery, alias

I have a sql query in MS-Access which (when simplified to its basic structure) runs like this:

```
SELECT 
  tableA.id, tableB.id
FROM
  (SELECT table.id FROM [table] WHERE (id mod 2 = 0)) AS tableA
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT table.id FROM [table] WHERE (id mod 3 = 0)) AS tableB
  ON tableA.id = tableB.id
;
```

That returns id's 6, 12 and so forth, for both A and B.

When adapting the script to MySQL it doesn't recognize the alias in the subqueries. I can't find a parallel in MySQL, what would it be?

Comment: What do you mean by "the alias in the subqueries"? What's the alias? `table`? `id`?

Comment: I assume `tableA` and `tableB`. @DBS: is there an error message? What does "doesn't recognize" mean?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. And sorry for the typo!... I can't believe I lost 2 hours with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table` is not a good choice for a table name.  Despite that name, your query works in MySQL 5.6 if you substitute backquotes for the square brackets.

```sql
SELECT 
  tableA.id, tableB.id
FROM
  (SELECT table.id FROM `table` WHERE (id mod 2 = 0)) AS tableA
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT table.id FROM `table` WHERE (id mod 3 = 0)) AS tableB
  ON tableA.id = tableB.id
;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/acd64/3/0)

That version of the query should also work in Access because Access SQL accepts either square brackets or backquotes as delimiters for object names.

Comment: HansUp Thank you for the answer! I know `table` is not a good name - that was a simplified version of the original query (maybe oversimplified ;). And YES it worked. I thought this syntax wouldn't apply to MySQL, but it was just a typo =P